# Некоторые случаи употребления скобок

Tags: пунктуация

1) С большой или маленькой буквы (или по желанию) должен начинается текст в скобках, если скобки эти открываются сразу после точки (или знаков **!** **?**).
Приведите примеры, только не с именем в скобках – это понятно.

2)  Ошибкой ли будет поставить в цитируемом предложении скобки до знака вопроса и почему? В скобках – подсказка выбирающему страну.

> Германия или Венгрия (нужно выбрать наугад)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Если **перед** скобкой стоит **любой** знак препинания (точка, троеточие, восклицательный или вопросительный знак), это означает:
   предыдущее предложение закончилось;
   новое предложение начинается в скобках.
   Начинается оно — не по желанию, а "в обязательном порядке"! — с большой буквы и заканчивается знаком препинания внутри скобок.

Вот примеры (без имени в скобках).
1. *Как будто в игру играешь – не зная правил, не зная, кто еще играет, сомневаясь насчет цели игры. Он кто – пешка или игрок? Его одолевает паранойя? («Как, еще не одолела?» – переспросила Джулия в голове.)*
2. *Лучше бы в конце предъявить ей историю целиком, обвязанную красной атласной лентой: «Поздравляю, вы оказались подлинной наследницей рода Романовых!» (И если что – нет, с клиентами Джексона ничего подобного не приключалось.)*
К. Аткинсон. Чуть свет, с собакою вдвоем

2. Германия или Венгрия (нужно выбрать наугад)?
   Пунктуация правильна, но смысл предложения воспринимается не сразу.
   Я бы написала так: **Германия или Венгрия (выбрать наугад).**
   Тогда и вопросительный знак не нужен – одну из стран просто выбираем наугад.

[Вставные словосочетания и предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/727-211_vstavnye_slovosochetaniya_i_predlozheniya.html)

Comment: Но ведь троеточие не всегда означает конец предложения, может ли быть продолжение предложения в скобках с маленькой буквы в таких случаях?

Comment: **_Теоретически_** такая конструкция, наверно, возможна (но мне ни разу не попадалась). Тогда она должна выглядеть так (абстрактно): _Первая часть предложения... (вставка) вторая часть предложения._

Comment: А вот так можно? _Начало предложения (часть вставки. Часть вставки) конец предложения._ Можно было бы точкой с запятой пользоваться на месте точки в примере, но интересно в теории как.

Comment: Да, так возможно, но при условии что "Часть вставки" оканчивается знаком препинания. Вот, смотрите: _Подкараулил этого кота гражданин в тот момент, когда животное с вороватым видом (**что же поделаешь, что у котов такой вид? Это не оттого, что они порочны, а оттого, что они боятся, чтобы кто-либо из существ более сильных, чем они – собаки и люди – не причинили им какой-нибудь вред или обиду. И то и другое очень нетрудно, но чести в этом, уверяю, нет никакой. Да, нет никакой!**), да, так с вороватым видом кот собирался устремиться зачем-то в лопухи (Булг.)._

Comment: У Лопатина есть такое: *"Перед открывающей скобкой может стоять многоточие, если оно требуется контекстом: <...> Это... (вот фамилию Монахов забыл) мой мастер (Бит.)"* (§ 158.3).

Comment: С Новым годом, *Nektoid*! Поясните, пожалуйста, комментарий.

Answer (score 1):

1) *А где стара? (Так он обыкновенно называл жену свою.)*

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=123#pp123

Эта вставная конструкция является отдельным предложением, но при этом она поясняет слово в предыдущем предложении.

2) *Германия или Венгрия (нужно выбрать наугад)?*

Эта вставная конструкция входит в предложение, а знак (любой) переносится и ставится после скобок.

Comment: 2) Вам не кажется, что если поставить скобки после вопроса, то читателю будет понятнее? В любому случаи, вынести эти скобки будет не ошибкой ведь?

Comment: Поставьте. Тогда получится: Германия или Венгрия? (Нужно выбрать наугад.)

Comment: Если выносим скобки в отдельное предложение, то замыкающий знак обязательно пишем внутри скобок?

Comment: Да, в ПАС тоже об этом говорится: § 99. Перед закрывающей скобкой ставится знак, фиксирующий конец вставного предложения: ...Так будет дальновиднее... (У Маслова клокотало в горле, хотя говорит он тихо и даже вяло.) Со дня рожденья четверть века справлял в дубраве Курский Соловей. (Немалый срок и в жизни человека, а соловью ~ тем паче юбилей!) .(Мих.).http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=128#pp128